# Centering a Div, containing images and text

Tags: html, css

```css
.clear{clear:both}
.div-main-container{width:100%}
.div-left-side{width:12%;float:left}
.div-right-side{width:80%;float:left;margin-top: 3%}

.sell-banner{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:10px;

}
.sell-title{
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-size:50px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-weight:bold;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.sell-detail{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
    text-weight:bold;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.astericks{
    font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
    margin-top:15px;
    padding-top:15px;
    font-size: 13px;
```

```html
<div class="sell-title">Create Your Online Food Store with Yodega</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

    
<div class="sell-banner">
    <a href="https://staging.yodega.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Screen-Shot-2017-08-13-at-1.39.13-PM.png"><img src="https://staging.yodega.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Screen-Shot-2017-08-13-at-1.39.13-PM-1024x350.png"  class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-452" /></a>
    </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="sell-detail">Do you make a food or drink product people are crazy about? Grow your business and sell nationwide with Yodega!</div>
<div class="div-main-container">
<div class="div-left-side">
        <img src="<a href="https://staging.yodega.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/yYodegaLogo.png"><img src="https://staging.yodega.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/yYodegaLogo.png" alt="" width="501" height="501" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-54" /></a></div>
<div class="div-right-side">
<div class="div-right-ele-heading">Insanely Easy & Fast Store Set Up</div>
<div class="div-right-normal-text">Create your store in 10 minutes with no programming hassles</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div-main-container">
<div class="div-left-side">
      <img src="/images/yodegaY.png" /></div>
<div class="div-right-side">
<div class="div-right-ele-heading">Zero Set Up Cost: Free Store & Listings</div>
<div class="div-right-normal-text">Your only cost is very small selling fees*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div-main-container">
<div class="div-left-side">
      <img src="/images/yodegaY.png" /></div>
<div class="div-right-side">
<div class="div-right-ele-heading">Your Own Personal Store with Custom URL</div>
<div class="div-right-normal-text">Create your own custom branded store page with direct web link</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div-main-container">
<div class="div-left-side">
      <img src="/images/yodegaY.png" /></div>
<div class="div-right-side">
<div class="div-right-ele-heading">Hassle-Free: Yodega Takes Care of Everything</div>
<div class="div-right-normal-text">Seller tools & dashboard makes selling a breeze</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div-main-container">
<div class="div-left-side">
      <img src="/images/yodegaY.png" /></div>
<div class="div-right-side">
<div class="div-right-ele-heading">Reduce Your Fee Rate with Referrals</div>
<div class="div-right-normal-text">Each seller you refer permanently reduces your fee rate**</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="astericks">

*base rate (4.9%) + typical credit card processing fees

**A vaild referral requires a recommendation within 1 month of referral store opening. Store must sell $300 of sales before referral rate reduction activates. Maximium .9% in reduction from standard fee rate from referral incentives.</div>
    
    </div>


<div id="buttons">
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button1">Sign Up</button>
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Seller Resources</button
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

curious how I would go about centering the content in the middle of the screen here? Starting with the y logo image. Also looking for a way to keep this nicely organized on mobile. I basically only need to center the contents in the div (not center the text).

div title = div-main-container

[image]

Site: https://staging.yodega.com/sell/

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code, so we can help

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Eek, my bad. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

To center the div you would use:

```
div { margin: 0 auto; }
```

As for keeping it organized on mobile, I would first suggest adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in your `<head></head>`, as well as using bootstrap which uses classes that scale your elements nicely to mobile platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the info - adding {margin: 0 auto;} doesn't seem to get the desired result. Updated with full relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

To center the div, use the following:

```
.div-main-container {margin: 0 auto;}
```

or

```
#div-main-container {margin: 0 auto;}
```

(Depends if you are using ID or Class. ID uses a #.) That will center the div itself, not the content.

Comment: Thanks for the info - adding {margin: 0 auto;} doesn't seem to get the desired result. Updated with full relevant code.